# Azure Worker role Webapi hosting + Service Bus

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I would like to be able to pump messages from the azure service bus and dispatch them to Webapi controllers in a worker role. I have seen this excellent (series) article http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/asp-net-web-api-creating-an-host-using-azure-service-bus/ which is very interesting but seems to use WCF . I would prefer to use the newer webapi framework instead. Has anyone already wrapped QueueClient as a source for a custom host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post that you refer does use the newer Web API framework. Internally, it uses the WCF relay bindings similarly to what happens with Web API self-hosting, which also uses WCF internally.

The code is available here: https://github.com/pmhsfelix/WebApi.Explorations.ServiceBusRelayHost

Hope this helps

Pedro

Comment: Thanks pedro, it helps a lot. I have done something similar on my side but will will definitely learn from project.